# Estimating Joint Probabilities from Marginal Probabilities

Tags: r, probability, python, estimation, joint-distribution

Given 2 categorical variables and their marginal probabilities of variable C. What is a good simple way of estimating the joint probabilities?
Let C be a Boolean T/F survey variable. For example: Liking "apple sauce"

[image]

Would it help if we knew the population counts for joint probabilities?

Naive Bayes gives believable values. Wondering if there are more accurate methods?

```
0.035  0.75  0.25
0.25   0.96  0.75
0.1    0.9
```

Comment: Of possible interest:  http://anakena.dcc.uchile.cl/~mnmonsal/algo2.pdf and
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2348339?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents.

Comment: Thank you for the second paper. Googling "Estimation in Contingency Tables with Given Marginals" reveals several more. Sadly all behind paywalls...

Comment: Chris, could you try your local library?

Comment: This may be a good read: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/frogner19a/frogner19a.pdf

Comment: Also of interest:  https://stat.snu.ac.kr/johanlim/papers/gpcontingency.pdf.  This paper subsequently appeared in an issue of Statistician.